# cannot execute script with sudo no password

Tags: scripts, sudo

I would like to create a batch file that will connect via ssh to my ubuntu server and run a script. My batch file works by using plink, I can see that the call to my script is ran but then I'm asked for a password for sudo. The script I wrote forces a dlna service to reload its library. Only one line in the script file

```
sudo service minidlna force-reload
```

When I run the script and supply the password it produces the expected results. I've placed the script in `/usr/local/bin` and can call it directly by name: `reload_minidlna.sh` . (I don't think I need the .sh but I've been playing with this for days now.) I edited the sudoers file as follows to allow all users to execute this script without password:

```
ALL ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/reload_minidlna.sh
```

There are two lines under this line:

```
 #See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives: and
 #includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

This doesn't work however. I am always asked for the password either directly logged into the server or via batch file ssh to server. Am I missing something here?

Comment: This isn't really a good idea, but you could ssh into your root account (e.g. ssh root@yourip). Then you can run that command without writing sudo

Comment: I don't have the root account enabled because it's not really a good idea.

Comment: Yeah fair, another option is to add it to crontab on the server. So it will run automatically periodically rather than being accessed from an external computer

Comment: Have you tried removing the `sudo` from the `service minidlna force-reload` command in your script, and running the whole script with `sudo`? Remember, your sudoers line is giving NOPASSWD to the _script_ - not the commands _within_ the script.

Comment: @steeldriver write that in an answer. That was the key! Thanks a bunch!