# Remove execution of SH Script with Sudo, not Root

Tags: 16.04, scripts, ssh

I'm attempting to run a script via SSH on several servers, the commands inside almost all need to be executed via sudo.

I have been experimenting with various solutions [From this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305035/how-to-use-ssh-to-run-shell-script-on-a-remote-machine) as well as [this one](https://serverfault.com/questions/625641/how-can-i-run-arbitrarily-complex-command-using-sudo-over-ssh)

I have tried: -

```
ssh auser@10.27.xx.xxx 'echo "passwordgoeshere" | sudo -Sv && bash -s' < test5.sh arg1 arg2
```

Which runs successfully, but doesn't elevate, so every line of the script fails. As well as: -

```
base64 test5 arg1 arg2 | ssh auser@10.27.xx.xxx 'base64 -d | sudo bash'
```

Which gives the error sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified.

I have [seen from this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/410587/cannot-execute-script-with-sudo-no-password) that I could allow root login and solve all the problems, but I don't want to do that as it's insecure (as far as I understand it).

Does anyone know what I'm missing? If I expand the switches on the first one, it looks like it should work, the logic makes sense to me, so I am at a bit of a loss as to how to proceed.

Thanks! Finally, basically new poster, so if my formatting/level of depth is lacking, please let me know and I'll endeavour to correct.

Comment: If you're doing `ssh root@10.27.xx.xxx` aren't you already running it as root? why do you need `sudo` or `bash` at all in this case? (You've apparently permitted SSH root login, even though you may not have enabled interactive password-based login.)

Comment: Hi @Steeldriver apologies, that was me attempting different ways and not realising it when I reset - I haven't got root access enabled, that was just me trying stuff as I'd run out of ideas.

Comment: Where is your script located?

Comment: @muru  It's the last three bits of the first line. It's nothing complex, takes the two args and makes a few directories. Said directories are outside the home directory, so it requires sudo.

Comment: From your command, it looks like the script is located in the local system, not on the servers. Is that the case?

Comment: @muru, yes, but it doesn't have to be, could scp it over if that would make this work.